CollectionView imperformat Images in .net MAUI
We have an application where we want to display a large number of images (more than 30). Since each image has some unique features, we implemented a collection view using a custom control.
The collection view allows users to adjust the number of columns from one to three. This provides the flexibility to either focus on individual images or view a broader overview of all the pictures.
Each image is not stored as a link on the device; instead, it is saved as a byte[] in a SQLite database.
<CollectionView
x:Name="CollectionView"
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
IsVisible="{Binding ShowAttachments}"
ItemsSource="{Binding Attachments}">
<CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="{Binding GirdColumns}" />
</CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="activity:Attachment">
        <customControls:ImageControl
            Title="{Binding Comment, Mode=TwoWay}"
            ContainerHeightRequest="200"
            FavoriteCommand="{Binding Path=UpdateFavoriteStateCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type activityDetail:ActivityDetailViewModel}}}"
            FavoriteCommandParameter="{Binding .}"
            Glyph="chat_bubble"
            ImageDoubleTappedCommand="{Binding Path=GoToEditViewOnAttachmentDoubleTappedCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type activityDetail:ActivityDetailViewModel}}}"
            ImageDoubleTappedCommandParameter="{Binding .}"
            ImageSource="{Binding Data, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter}}"
            ImageTappedCommand="{Binding Path=ShowAttachmentDetailCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type activityDetail:ActivityDetailViewModel}}}"
            ImageTappedCommandParameter="{Binding .}"
            ImageWidthRequest="180"
            IsFavorite="{Binding IsFavorite}"
            QuickActionCommand="{Binding Path=ShowChatCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type activityDetail:ActivityDetailViewModel}}}"
            QuickActionCommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

Image Control:
<Border
x:Class="SomeAwesomeNamespace.Controls.ImageControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Name="ImageControlItem"
Padding="5"
HeightRequest="330"
Stroke="Black"
StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 5">
<Grid BindingContext="{x:Reference ImageControlItem}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Aspect="AspectFit"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        MaximumHeightRequest="250"
        Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
        VerticalOptions="Start">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer
                Command="{Binding ImageTappedCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding ImageTappedCommandParameter}"
                NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />

        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
    <VerticalStackLayout
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalOptions="End">

        <Button
            Margin="3"
            Padding="0"
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
            Command="{Binding ImageDoubleTappedCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding ImageDoubleTappedCommandParameter}"
            HeightRequest="40"
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            WidthRequest="40">
            <Button.ImageSource>
                <FontImageSource
                    FontFamily="IconFont"
                    Glyph="edit"
                    Size="20" />
            </Button.ImageSource>
        </Button>
        <Button
            Margin="3"
            Padding="0"
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
            Command="{Binding FavoriteCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding FavoriteCommandParameter}"
            HeightRequest="40"
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            WidthRequest="40">
            <Button.ImageSource>
                <FontImageSource
                    FontFamily="IconFont"
                    Glyph="{Binding IsFavorite, Converter={StaticResource VisibleInvisibleIconConverter}}"
                    Size="20" />
            </Button.ImageSource>
        </Button>
    </VerticalStackLayout>

    <Editor
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        HeightRequest="80"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
        Opacity="0.7"
        Placeholder="Notiz"
        Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}"
        VerticalOptions="End" />
    <Button
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Padding="5"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
        Command="{Binding QuickActionCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding QuickActionCommandParameter}"
        CornerRadius="15"
        HeightRequest="30"
        HorizontalOptions="End"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        WidthRequest="30">
        <Button.ImageSource>
            <FontImageSource
                FontFamily="IconFont"
                Glyph="{Binding Glyph}"
                Size="15"
                Color="{StaticResource White}" />
        </Button.ImageSource>
    </Button>

</Grid>

The issue with this implementation is that if we have a large number of images (more than 30), the application lags. Additionally, when importing images using the "MPowerKit.MediaPlugin" and the number exceeds 10, the application crashes with the following error:
android
Exception - This event
error
02:59:52.000 PM
RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@446f22f
Network Event
info
02:59:51.623 PM
{
action: NETWORK_CAPABILITIES_CHANGED,
download_bandwidth: 28154,
network_type: cellular,
upload_bandwidth: 20245,
vpn_active: false
}
Exception
fatal
02:59:51.513 PM
Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@446f22f
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics
warning
02:59:50.832 PM
Mismatch between the specified x:DataType (Someawesome.nampespace.Features.Activities.Attachment) and the current binding context (Someawesome.nampespace.UI.Controls.ImageControl).
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics
warning
02:59:50.823 PM
Mismatch between the specified x:DataType (Someawesome.nampespace.Features.Activities.Attachment) and the current binding context (Someawesome.nampespace.UI.Controls.ImageControl).
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics
warning
02:59:50.819 PM
Mismatch between the specified x:DataType (Someawesome.nampespace.Features.Activities.Attachment) and the current binding context (Someawesome.nampespace.UI.Controls.ImageControl).
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics
warning
02:59:50.811 PM
Mismatch between the specified x:DataType (Someawesome.nampespace.Features.Activities.Attachment) and the current binding context (Someawesome.nampespace.UI.Controls.ImageControl).
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics
warning
02:59:50.805 PM
Mismatch between the specified x:DataType (Someawesome.nampespace.Features.Activities.Attachment) and the current binding context (Someawesome.nampespace.UI.Controls.ImageControl).
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics
warning
02:59:50.797 PM
Mismatch between the specified x:DataType (Someawesome.nampespace.Features.Activities.Attachment) and the current binding context (Someawesome.nampespace.UI.Controls.ImageControl).
ios
WatchdogTermination: The OS watchdog terminated your app, possibly because it overused RAM.
It seems we are facing issues displaying the newly added data. Is there an efficient way to handle many images in a collection view?
thx for your help! <3
Update:
I changed the workflow so that the images, which will be stored in the database, will be copied to the application's directory.
private async Task LoadImagesToLocalStorage(Guid activityId, Attachment attachment)

{
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attachment.LocalPath) && File.Exists(attachment.LocalPath))
{
return;
}
// Ensure the directory exists
var cacheDir = FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory;
var localFilePath = Path.Combine(cacheDir, attachment.Name);

if (File.Exists(localFilePath))
{
    attachment.LocalPath = localFilePath;
}
else
{
    try
    {
        // create stream from byte array    
        using MemoryStream sourceStream = new MemoryStream(attachment.Data);
        await using FileStream localFileStream = File.Open(localFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(localFileStream);
        attachment.LocalPath = localFilePath;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(e, e.Message);
        return;
    }
}

await _attachmentDatabase.SaveAttachment(activityId, attachment, CancellationToken.None)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);

}
The performance difference is huge! So it works good. The question is, if saving the images there is the "correct" way, or if there is a better way to create a local copy of images

the first thing I'd check would be loading images from the db - this is usually not a great solution.  Try storing them on disk instead to see if that improves performance

Yep, but the idea is, that we have it like telegram. This means images, which will be loaded from the server should be stored locally without saving them into the gallery because this would mean, that is could be saved to any cloud easily.

you can save them locally without saving to a gallery.  Just store them on disk as files instead of in the db.

I recommend you store thumbnails in your schema. Use thumbnails to populate the gallery. Use high resolution images on items that you select.

@Dom saving files on disk had problems in the past. If you save image, it will show at first. But if you replace the content of the image, the output will show the old image. So keep this in mind. A solution to this includes was to clear every cached file. (Android specific problem).

This problem with images and recycle view has two different solutions. One of them was some platform specific code about buffers/loading etc... (cant remember, shouldn't be too hard to find). The second one - the one I used is to set Width/Height of the images. The biggest problem was, that this was not behaving the same way on all devices. Some device would crash immediately, some at scroll, some would never crash.

The biggest performance improvement was to change the ImageSource to a path.
And for this, we implemented a way so save a local copy to the storage.
